# T-SQL Table name alias

Tags: t-sql, variables

In my T-SQL script, I refer to same long table name several times. I use this query on different tables.

Is there a way to refer a table name by variable? If so, I can simple declare one variable at the top which script will use and just by setting value, I can run it on various tables without making changes in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a synonym for that table but obviously you'd need to make sure that nobody changed the definition of the synonym whilst the script was running (and no parallel invocations of the script)

Are you running these in SSMS? If so you could set `SQL CMD` mode (on the "Query" menu) and use

```
:setvar tablename "spt_values" 

use master

select * from $(tablename)
```

Answer (score 9):

A couple of options.

**Within a single SQL statement you can alias table names like so:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM MySuperLongTableName T
WHERE T.SomeField=1
```

If you need to do this over lots of statements across several scripts a synonym might be a better option:

```
CREATE SYNONYM SuperT FOR dbo.MySuperLongTableName
```

Comment: Neat!  However, in my attempt to demonstrate that it does work, I found I needed to put a "for" keyword between the synonym and the object name.  As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx.  Does it work for you without the "for"?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as such:

```
Declare @TableName As nvarchar(max)
Declare @SQL AS nvarchar(max)
@TableName = 'longtablename'

@SQL = 'Select * From ' + @TableName
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL, Ugh! This has all sorts of side-effects the OP might not want related to permissions and recompiling query plans.

Comment: @JohnFx, well he asked for a way to do it, and there honestly isn't anything wrong with Dynamix SQL if you know what you're doing. Also if you're changing tables you are going to have all of those issues anyways.

Comment: I didn't catch the part about switching out the table name like a variable. In that case Dynamic SQL might be the best option. However, I still say use it as a last resort.

Comment: @JohnFx, I'm not saying it's the prettiest way to do things, just probably the simplest

Comment: I'm agreeing with you (since my last comment). No need to convince me.