# How to update the PK of every record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables that are exactly the same, except for one column. Both tables have the same amount of records and the same amount of columns, and all of the data is the same.

```
Table A:
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+
|                 GUID                 | Animal | Person | Vehicle |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+
| 1D001609-7071-4DBB-9E65-0000B3EEF751 | cat    | matt   | car     |
| 90260783-E3C3-4A9B-BEA0-000388EA41E1 | dog    | rich   | truck   |
| DD18FCFA-99BD-4FBC-AFC2-00058EF95D0A | zebra  | alex   | van     |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+



Table B:
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+
|                 GUID                 | Animal | Person | Vehicle |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+
| F67A3079-8589-4304-AA3C-000688696BAA | cat    | matt   | car     |
| C71710EC-492F-424E-805D-00068AFE4E82 | dog    | rich   | truck   |
| 5F830142-F4CC-4580-974D-000710F1AB5F | zebra  | alex   | van     |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I need the GUIDs of table A to be updated to equal the GUIDs of Table B. Something like this will work:

```
update a
set a.guid=b.guid
from tablea a
join tableb b
on a.animal=b.animal
and a.person=b.person
and a.vehicle=b.vehicle
```

But the above solution will not work for me. I have actually approximately 50 columns and about 1 million records.

Would you have any other suggestions on how to update the GUID in table A more efficiently?

Comment: Why not just regen the table without the column you dont want?

Comment: too slow. i was thinking maybe i could take the hash of every row minus the first column and compare the records that way

Comment: @MikeCheel regenerating the table will change the GUIDs

Comment: Turn identity off, regen then turn it back on?

Comment: If you want them to be exactly the same except in name, then why not use a [SYNONYM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5174470/1810429)?  How is each table _being used_?

Comment: @MikeCheel  GUIDs are randomly generated by using newid()

Comment: @J0e3gan i need the GUIDs to match up. i have layers of dependencies on the GUIDs and those dependencies haev already been generated, so it's expecting specific GUIDs

Comment: If everything is the same then just replace Table A with Table B.

Comment: Could you drop the primary key, update it, and they re-apply it? You'd need to drop because there's the risk of another row having the same updated GUID.

Comment: I get that part.  What I don't get yet is why you need two tables that only differ in name in the first place.

Comment: @RickS everything except for GUID

Comment: Sorry, doesn't make sense to me. If both tables have EXACTLY the same data (except the guids you want are in Table B) then just overwrite Table A with Table B.  What am I missing?

Comment: Drop table B and use table A instead.

Comment: @RickS thank you for helping me think about this. the question is that i need a specific GUID to match to a specific GUID in another table. how would i do that?

Comment: Do you have a mechanism in place to keep the GUIDs in sync after you've done this?  Why even go through all the effort of maintaining two identical tables?

Comment: You can use SQL SERVER Import export wizard for this, just select delete existing rows from destination table before importing data

Comment: Why do you want to update the GUIDs? That's the point- Guaranteed unique. IMO don't use GUIDs for PK- use them for constraint. And it seems you may have an extra table if the data in them is the same. What are you trying to accomplish with this (or why are you doing this) might be the better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET [GUID] = (
  SELECT [GUID] 
  FROM B
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT A.Animal,A.Person,A.Vehicle
    INTERSECT
    SELECT B.Animal,B.Person,B.Vehicle
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tables identical, how about this:

```
DROP TABLE B

SELECT *
INTO B
FROM A
```

Comment: This won't keep the primary keys and other constraints on B.  Far better to TRUNCATE TABLE B;  Then reinsert the rows.  This will preserve the table definition.